# Access hidden HTML tags before user interaction

Tags: java, html, web-scraping, dom, web-inspector

I have a website that whenever user clicks on this button, the website will display a data table and the  tag for that will appear in the inspection tool. I want to retrieve this data table information via the HTML content when I scrape this website. However, the URL stays the same no matter the button is clicked or not. Technically I can't get the content with just the URL because it will open the website content when the button is not clicked (or no table displayed). I'm coding in Java. How can I get around this?

---

My example:
[image]

Here there are two div tags with the exact same class name "sKfxWe-BeDmAc sKfxWe-BeDmAc-AHe6Kc" with two same child div tags, but their contents are different. The thing is the second div tag only appears when I click a button on the page -- basically it renders a different content. The fact that the URL stays the same and the second div tag isn't there when the page's first rendered make it hard for me to get its content.

Comment: Are you using selenium?
Selenium should offer some simple ways to handle this.
Can you share some of your code or the HTML you are trying to access?
If you're using selenium, you can copy the class/attribute or xpath to the element using the browser dev-tools. You can then use driver.find_element_by<xpath/class/etc> etc

Comment: @DonCarleone  I just edited my post. I don't think I can trace the attribute since it's not even there before I click on a button

Comment: important technical note: html tags only exist in source code, not in running web pages. HTML tags in source code get transformed into DOM node elements on running pages. You can get elements _by_ tag, but you can't "get tags". That might seem nitpicking, but knowing the correct terms means you can also search for solutions using the correct terms, and find answers. Rather than searching on the wrong terms and not finding anything useful.